# Regex on bytes in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I would like to extract 10.00ML in following byte: b'\x0200S10.00ML\x03'
So I've tried extracting the 10.00ML between 200S and \x03:

```py
result = re.search(b'200S(.*)x03', b'\x0200S10.00ML\x03')
```

which didn't work, no element was found:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Using only strings I have a minimum working example:

```
test_string = 'a3223b'
result = re.search('a(.*)b', test_string)
print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: The characters `x03` do not actually appear in that string, that's just part of an escape sequence.  You would need the preceding backslash as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = b'\x0200S10.00ML\x03'
m = re.search(rb'\x0200S(.*?)\x03', text, re.S)
if m:
    print( m.group(1).decode('utf-8') )

# => 10.00ML
```

Note that `\x02` and `\x03` are START OF HEADING and START OF TEXT control chars, so you cannot match them as literal text.